# Discord.py how would I add a command to clear out a certain amount of messages from a channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am looking to add a feature to my basic bot that will purge a number of messages in the channel
i.e

***!purge 50***

Will then delete 50 messages from the current channel.

Comment: This is quite easy if you just take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge). They are very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this really easily. Using [purge](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge), you can make this command.

By the way, please look at the docs before asking a question here. It would save everyone time.